# Change primary text color of the theme in Vuetify 2 on runtime

Tags: vue.js, frontend, vuetify.js

I allow the user to change the main primary color of the application by using any hexadecimal color by calling:

```
changeTheme(color){
  Vuetify.framework.theme.themes.light.primary = color
}
```

the problem is that if the chosen color is too bright or dark, the text color can't be read.

[image]
is there is something like this? ==>

```
changeTheme(color, textColor){
  Vuetify.framework.theme.themes.light.primary = color <== This line works
  Vuetify.framework.theme.themes.light.primaryText = textColor <== This not
}
```

I need to apply the changes too all the places where primary color is being used, app-bar, buttons...etc. I also have a toggle between dark and light mode, so I need to be sure that the color text doesn't change when switching between modes.

Comment: I would also like to know the answer to this. I am attempting to write a component to allow users to change certain colours within the app and text colour is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

My solution

vuetify.js

```
export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'md'
  },
  theme: {
    // dark: true,
    // theme: { disable: true },
    options: { customProperties: true },//add this
    themes: {
      light: {
        primary2: colors.indigo.base,//add this 
        primary2Text: colors.shades.white//You can also use localStorage.getItem('XXX')
      },
      dark: {
        // primary: colors.blue.lighten3,
        background: colors.grey.base
      }
    }
  }
});
```

vue

```
<v-app-bar app class="appbar"></v-app-bar>
.appbar,
.footer {
  background-color: var(--v-primary2-base) !important;
  color: var(--v-primary2Text-base) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Color values are available on the instance $vuetify object under the theme property. This allows you to dynamically modify your theme. Vuetify will regenerate and update your theme classes, seamlessly updating your application.

```
// Light theme
this.$vuetify.theme.themes.light.primary = '#4caf50'

// Dark theme
this.$vuetify.theme.themes.dark.primary = '#4caf50'
```

[documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/#customizing)

Comment: The question is more oriented on detecting how dark or light is a color so the text can adapt dynamically. It needs to support HSL colors to make the calculation at runtime https://css-tricks.com/switch-font-color-for-different-backgrounds-with-css/#working-with-hsl-colors-and-css-variables

Comment: Hi @ctwhome, Thanks for pointing that. OK now I think what helps is setting colors for light & dark in vuetify options like: textDark: '#000', textLight: '#fff' and use these colors in template like: class="textDark--text". Hope that works.